# Can three perpendicular bisectors determine a triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

I would like to know if it is possible to determine the sides of a triangle given the lengths of the three perpendicular bisectors.
Assume that the three perpendicular bisectors intersect at $P$ and intersects $a, b, c$ respectively at $K, L, M$, and let the lengths of $PK, PL, PM$ be $p_a, p_b, p_c$ which is given. Is it possible to determine the lengths of $a, b, c$?

We know that
$$\frac {a^2}{4}+p_a^2=\frac {b^2}{4}+p_b^2=\frac {c^2}{4}+p_c^2=r^2$$
Where $r$ is the radius of the circumscribed circle.
Additionally, we have
$$\frac{1}{2}(ap_a+bp_b+cp_c)=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$
And by substitution, we have
$$a^2+4p_a^2=\frac{a^2(a^2+4p_a^2-4p_b^2)(a^2+4p_a^2-4p_c^2)}{a^2(a^2+4p_b^2-4p_c^2)}$$
What to do next?

Comment: Is $P$ assumed to be an internal point of the triangle?

Comment: @user It will be an internal point in an acute triangle to make things easier. But other types of triangle are much less similar right?

Comment: I have rewritten my answer . Please check.

Comment: Here’s [a demonstration of the possibility of two distinct solutions](https://www.desmos.com/geometry/lpbylooyyg). By adjusting the position of A until one of C or C′ lies on the circumcircle (blue), we can obtain two distinct triangles (△ABC and △ABC′) that fit the conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To incorporate all possible cases it is convenient to allow the values $p_i$ be signed, negative sign meaning that the side $i$ lies against the obtuse angle. There can be only one negative $p_i$ and it has to be the least of three by the absolute value. If all three $p_i$ are positive or the least by the absolute value is negative and two other are positive the solution always exists and is unique.

The finding of $a,b,c$ can be reduced to finding the circumradius $r$. For this one should solve the equation:
$$
\arccos\frac{p_a}r+\arccos\frac{p_b}r+\arccos\frac{p_c}r=\pi.\tag1
$$
Using the formula
$$
\cos(x+y+z)=\cos x\cos y\cos z-\cos x\sin y\sin z-\sin x\cos y\sin z-\sin x\sin y\cos z
$$
one can after some straightforward algebra reduce the equation $(1)$ to:
$$
r^3-3pr-2q=0.\tag2
$$
with
$$
p=\frac{p_a^2+p_b^2+p_c^2}3,\quad q=p_a p_b p_c.\tag3
$$

This cubic equation has [depressed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Depressed_cubic) and can be easily solved. Since due to [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) we have in general
$$
-p^3+q^2\le0 
$$
the equation has three real roots and we need the largest one.

The simplest way to represent the required soluton of $(2)$ is to use the [trigonometric form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Three_real_roots):
$$
r=2p^{1/2}\cos\left[\frac13\arccos\left(\frac q{p^{3/2}}\right)\right].\tag4
$$

Comment: A complete answer is given in theorem 7 [here](https://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2013volume13/FG201307.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie This article defines the elements $(p_a,p_b,p_c)$ differently as it is done in the question.

Comment: You are perfectly right. How I hadn't seen it ?